# Click the UI Button to Import 3D object from local folder in UNITY?

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, local-storage

ON click the UI button to import 3d object or FBX from local folder in COMPUTER and how to access the local folder in runtime ?? (UNITY3D)

Thank YOU

Comment: Please describe what you've done so far

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write your own File Browser (or use someone's else). Then using some FBX reader nuget package interact with Unity API... It's really not easy. You may want to see this thread - [How can I load FBX file in Unity runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51701361/how-can-i-load-fbx-file-in-unity-runtime) .